# Adding gmail to your created app

Tags: android, gmail, custom-application

I am creating a task organizer for my android device.  I am trying to allow the organizer to schedule its tasks on the gmail calendar directly from my created app.  Every time I search for this I get results on how to use google apps, not the ability to integrate them within my own app.  I know this information must exist somewhere.  Is it possible someone can point me in the right direction or shed some light on this situation in general.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the google calendar API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Comment: Thank you this seems to be exactly what I need!